Would somebody please remove the period in the name of the "Astronomy." stack exchange?
It's probably trivial, but it gets on my nerves every time I see it. No other SE has a period after its name.
Shoot me; I'm a perfectionist.

Where are you seeing a period in the site's name?

oh hell! in my hi-contrast font, the underline at the end looks like a period. sorry.

I'm not seeing any period:


oh hell! in my hi-contrast font, the underline at the end looks like a period. sorry.

oh hell! in my hi-contrast font, the underline at the end looks like a period. sorry. canceling question.
